# Why does one need to restart the PC now after installing V 13.1?

Tags: installation

I've installed Mathematica new releases before on my PC.

This is the first time it asks to restart the PC at the end of the installation of V 13.1. This is on windows 10.

[image]

The question is, why in this version one needs to restart the PC?

Just curious that is all. It not a big deal to restart the PC. Just wondering why only this happened in this version and in none of the earlier versions of Mathematica as far as I remember.

Comment: Is version 13.1 already available for downloading for everyone? It wasn't announced yet...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yes, it is available. I downloaded it from the my user portal account. see chat also, others have downloaded it and installed it.

Comment: Is it still possible to manually set the number of parallel kernels in V 13.1 like in previous versions?

Comment: @Nasser What is the release id for your version of 13.1: `AssociationMap[SystemInformation[#,"ReleaseID"]&,{"Kernel","FrontEnd"}]`?

Comment: @user13892 will let you know once I restart my PC. I have not been able to do that yet, as I am running a program which takes days to finish something. Once it is done, will let you know.

Comment: @user13892  fyi, here is the info screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcxCM.png)

Comment: @Nasser thank you! I am using `WolframDesktop` and my release id is slightly different from yours. I guess they use a different release id for `Mathematica` vs `WolframDesktop`. But I had to restart as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

13.1 and later are using the dynamic version of Microsoft's C++ Runtime library.  If another application was using it when the installer was run, then you might need to reboot your machine.